# remove spaces in bbcode Values aftar "]" AND befor "["

Tags: php, bbcode

Is there a way to correct the input before it is used by trim() or other ??

The input must first be corrected From

```
[youtube]       IHu9-Q30Nuw     [/youtube] 
texttexttext


texttext

[code]               codecodecode  codecode codecodecode
codecodecode



codecodecode
[/code]
```

to

```
[youtube]IHu9-Q30Nuw[/youtube] 
texttexttext


texttext

[code]codecodecode  codecode codecodecode
codecodecode



codecodecode[/code]
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

finally did it :)

**input + code**

```
// input -------------------
$OLDtext = "[youtube]       IHu9-Q30Nuw     [/youtube] 
texttexttext


texttext

[code]               codecodecode  codecode codecodecode
codecodecode



codecodecode
[/code] 
";

// code -------------------
$NEWtext = preg_replace_callback("/\[(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/(.*?)\]/ism"
                                , 
                                function($match) 
                                {
                                    $TEMPtext   = preg_replace('/\]\s+/', ']', $match[0]); 
                                    return preg_replace('/\s+(\[+)/', '$1', $TEMPtext);
                                }
                                , 
                                $OLDtext
                            );
// print -------------------
echo nl2br($NEWtext);
```

**output**

```
[youtube]IHu9-Q30Nuw[/youtube] 
texttexttext


texttext

[code]codecodecode  codecode codecodecode
codecodecode



codecodecode[/code]
```